# How do i display specific column values on console?

Tags: selenium

My following code displays all the column values of a particular row successfully but the value of column 3 is printing twice, how do i solve? And there are total 10 columns and i want to print/display the values of the column 1,3 and 7 only.
What changes need to be done in the following code?

```
int rows_count = patientList.size();

        for (int row=0; row< rows_count; row++)
        {
            List<WebElement> Columns_rows = patientList.get(row).findElements(By.tagName("div"));
            int columns_count = Columns_rows.size();
            for (int column=0; column < columns_count; column++)
            {
                String celtext = Columns_rows.get(column).getText();

                System.out.format("%16s", celltext);
            }System.out.println("\n");
        }
```

Comment: You should include the page's markup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1

> To find the 3,5 and 7th cell data you should use xpath of that columns
>   to locate it. for example:

```
dynamicxpath_7col=//*[@id='tableid']/table/tbody/tr[Columns_rows]//use variable for each row
Webelement 7thcolumn=Columns_rows.findelement(By.xpath("dynamicxpath"));
```

Option 2

```
int rows_count = patientList.size();

        for (int row=0; row< rows_count; row++)
        {
            List<WebElement> Columns_rows = patientList.get(row).findElements(By.tagName("div"));
            int columns_count = Columns_rows.size();
            for (int column=0; column < columns_count; column++)
            {
                String celtext = Columns_rows.get(column).getText();
                if(column==1 or column==5 or column==7)
                  System.out.format("%16s", celltext);

            }System.out.println("\n");
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, 2nd option worked for me  but some time it does not print the 2nd and 3rd value of the first row.

Comment: paste your HTML source(DOM) here for further investigation.

Comment: <div class="grid-canvas" style="width: 1663px; height: 270px;" xpath="1">
 <div class="ui-widget-content slick-row even" style="top:0px">
  <div class="custom-tooltip slick-cell l0 r0">
   JOHN, LIA  </div>
<div class="custom-tooltip slick-cell l1 r1">
 10/14/1968 </div>
<div class="custom-tooltip slick-cell l2 r2">
<div class="roster-careplan-tooltip" data-tooltip="3H483748209" style="overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;">
 3HZ9483480LUC309 </div>
<div class="custom-tooltip slick-cell l3 r3 Roster-Patient-Grid-Alt"></div>
<div class="custom-tooltip slick-cell l6 r6"> Lilli </div>

Comment: Hi Amruta, please check my new question, if you can help will be great help. Here is the link.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60324798/how-to-differentiate-the-answers-formatcheckbox-or-textarea-etc-while-working/60325793?noredirect=1#comment106717145_60325793