# how to differentiate the answers format(Checkbox or Textarea etc.) while working with for loop

Tags: selenium

I have a scenario where 15 questions are there and i do have to select the answer either by selecting radiobutton or checkbox or Yes/No button or have to enter some text in textarea.

My following code successfully selecting the answer randomly whether its a radio/checkbox or Yes/No button and displays the selected option as an answer along with question on console. 
But how do i check if its textarea and need to enter something with 'sendKeys?  And how do i select more than one checkboxes? And how do i display the answer Yes or No onconsole?

```
public void AssessmentTest() throws Exception
    {
    List<WebElement>totalQSN = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='assessmentQuestionAnswersContainer']/div"));

    List<WebElement> mainQuestions = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='assessmentQuestionAnswersContainer']/div/div[2]/div")); 

      System.out.println("The Questions are::");
            for(int i=0; i<totalQSN.size()-5; i++)
            {   
                System.out.println("QUESTION:- " + mainQuestions.get(i).getText() + "["+ i +"]" );

                Random rnd = new Random();
                List<WebElement> subOptions = totalQSN.get(i).findElements(By.tagName("input"));     
                WebElement sValue = subOptions.get(rnd.nextInt(subOptions.size()));
                sValue.click();
    List<WebElement> subQsnList = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='assessmentQuestionAnswersContainer']/div/div[3]/div/span/span"));
                System.out.println(subOptions.size());
                for(int j=0; j<subOptions.size(); j++)
                {   
                    if(subOptions.get(j).isSelected())
                 {
                     String selectedAnswer= subQsnList.get(j).getText();
                     System.out.println("ANSWER: - " + selectedAnswer);
                     System.out.println("\n");
                    }
                }
            } }
```

**HTML Code is as under for each type of question.**

```
<div id="individualQuestionAnswerContainer147" class="individual-question-answer-container" style="display: block;" xpath="1">
    <div class="individual-questions-count-container"></div>
    <div id="questionContainer147" style="clear: both; float: left;"></div> //Contains Question      
    <div id="questionAnswerContainer147" class="answers-container"></div> //Contains Answers        
</div>
```

**If the question having checkboxes, the code is**

```
<div id="individualQuestionAnswerContainer148" class="individual-question-answer-container" style="" xpath="2">  Contains 4 checkbox(divs)
    <div class="individual-questions-count-container"></div>
    <div id="questionContainer148" style="clear: both; float: left;"></div>
    <div id="questionAnswerContainer148" class="answers-container" style="">
        <div class="answer-text">
            <span class="answer-text-inner btn-assessment-answer">
                <input type="checkbox" name="Checkbox148" id="Checkbox449" class="radio-assessment-answer">
                <span style="display: table;">
                    Good
                </span>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="answer-text">
            <span class="answer-text-inner btn-assessment-answer">
                <input type="checkbox" name="Checkbox148" id="Checkbox450" class="radio-assessment-answer">
                <span style="display: table;">
                    Mold
                </span>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="answer-text"></div>
        <div class="answer-text"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**If question having 2 buttons(Yes/No), the code is**

```
<div id="individualQuestionAnswerContainer155" class="individual-question-answer-container" style="" xpath="7">  Contains 2 options Yes or No
    <div class="individual-questions-count-container"></div>
    <div id="questionContainer155" style="clear: both; float: left;"></div>
    <div id="questionAnswerContainer155" class="answers-container" style="">
        <input type="button" value="Yes" id="Button477" class="btnClass_155 btn-assessment-answer" style="">
        <input type="button" value="No" id="Button478" class="btnClass_155 buttonClicked btn-assessment-answer">
    </div>
</div>
```

**If question having textarea, the code is**

```
<div id="questionAnswerContainer38" class="answers-container" xpath="1">
    <textarea maxlength="50000" rows="2" cols="100" id="FreeTextarea38"></textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this structure..Hope this helps.

```
public void AssessmentTest() throws Exception
        {
        List<WebElement>totalQSN = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='assessmentQuestionAnswersContainer']/div"));//Assuming this xpath is correct

        List<WebElement> mainQuestions = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='assessmentQuestionAnswersContainer']/div/div[2]/div")); //Assuming this xpath is correct

          System.out.println("The Questions are::");
                for(int i=0; i<totalQSN.size()-5; i++)
                {   
                    System.out.println("QUESTION:- " + mainQuestions.get(i).getText() + "["+ i +"]" );

                    Random rnd = new Random();
                    String webeleTag=totalQSN.get(i).getTagName();

                    if(webeleTag.equals("input"))){

                        String webeleType=totalQSN.get(i).getAttribute("type");

                        switch(webeleType){
                        case:"checkbox":
                        //your code to select check box
                        case:"button":
                        //Only click event on answer
                        default:

                        }   

                    }
                    else if(webeleTag.equals("textarea")){
                    //your code
                    }

                    else{
                    //Not text area,checkbox or radio something else
                    }

            }

        }
```

Comment: Thanks Amruta, it worked for me. I do have 2 more question for the same. div"));
mainQuestions.get(i).getText()); gives either Question or Label.
If it start with 1,2,3.... or a,b,c... then its Question, otherwise its a label.
Personal Detail         System.out.println("Label:- " + mainQuestions.get(i).getText());
1. What is your name?   System.out.println("Question:- " + mainQuestions.get(i).getText());
a. Whats your address   System.out.println("Question:- " + mainQuestions.get(i).getText());
How do i write a code to differentiate question and label

Comment: List<WebElement> assessmentNames = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='ddlActiveAssessmentQuestionnaire']/ul/li/a/label")); this line gives me all 30 assessment name.  when i am trying to get that name with code  System.out.println("Assessment Name" + assessmentNames.get(a).getText(). it does not displays nothing.  HTML code for it is as below:

Comment: HTML code is as below:  <div id="ddlActiveAssessmentQuestionnaire" class="dd-container" style="width: 200px;" xpath="1">
 <div class="dd-select" style="width: 200px; background: transparent;"></div>
 <ul class="dd-options dd-click-off-close" style="min-width: 200px; overflow: auto; display: block;">
 <li></li>
 <li>
  <a class="dd-option">
   <input class="dd-option-value" type="hidden" value="6">
    <label class="dd-option-text"> 
    AD8
    </label></a></li><li></li> I want to print AD8 as an assessment name.

Comment: For your 1st question try to find out some attribute or tagname which are different for label and questions and handle this with xpath rather than checking for 123 or abc.And if there is not much difference in HTMl then use patterns with reg exp to check if it is questions or labels. Your 2nd questions is unclear to me.

Comment: There is no different in html code whether its a label or question. Just questions are prefix with 1,2,3... or a,b,c.... 2nd question: driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='ddlActiveAssessmentQuestionnaire']/ul/li/a/label")); gives me 30 elements(labels).  such as<label class="dd-option-text" xpath="1"></label>
<label class="dd-option-text" xpath="2">
AD8
</label>
<label class="dd-option-text" xpath="3">
Anxiety
</label>
<label class="dd-option-text" xpath="4"></label>
<label class="dd-option-text" xpath="5"></label>
I just want to display on console AD* and then Anxiety.

Comment: My second issue resolved.  WebElement Name= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='patient-slide-header patient-slide-header-h2']"));
  String pName= Name.getText().substring(7, 38);
  System.out.format("%18s", "Patient Name:- " + pName); Its giving correct output but pName prints on second line. I want to print it on same line.

Answer (score 0):

- To detect if it is a text area, from the top of my head you can go
  for `.getTagName()` this will return the tag of the element.
- To get all the checkboxes you can use `driver.findElements(By.id("questionAnswerContainer148")).toArray(new WebElement[0])` , this will return an array with the checkboxes and you can use some logic to click in the items you want from the list.
- For the yes/no, I think that the `driver.findElement(by).getAttribute("value")` will return the content of the attribute.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks but i don't know how do i use it if..else and put it all these options in a single code as one question having radiobuttons, second having checkboxes, 3rd having Yes/No buttons and fourth having say text area. How do i check and use it proper code.

Comment: I'm not an experienced coder, and not thinking in execution performance. You should not put everything in a single code because you will have a hard time to understand the code. Use methods or classes with miningful names to encapsulate part of the code (ex the validation if it is a text area like "isTextArea()".

Comment: Me too is not good experienced coder, so don't know how to use if..else in particularly above scenario.

Comment: Without doing big changes yes put an if to validate if the tag is textarea. If so sendKeys, else do the code you have. For the better coding part, try to find some books with that theme, or go to Github and check how other people do their code. And the most important thing, if you are repeating code make a method with it and call that method, if you are using that method in multiple classes create a class with it to use it in multiple parts of the code.

Comment: When I start a new project with a new language or framework, I tend to make the code like spaghetti hard to understand. But the next time I use a tool or add more code to a project I try to see what can I do to make it easy to understand, to make it more reusable or implement a different approach to the logic. I have done so many refactorings to a single test project in my past job, that if the 1st iteration of it compared with the last no one would say that they were the same project.